# How to Follow document from SharePoint document library (SharePoint online) on behalf of other users

Tags: c#, powershell, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I had achieved the functionality to follow the SharePoint document by using below code.

```
$.ajax({
            url: webUrl + "/_api/social.following/follow",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "actor": {
                    "__metadata": {
                        "type": "SP.Social.SocialActorInfo"
                    },
                    "ActorType": 1,
                    "ContentUri": DocumentUrl,
                    "Id": null

                }
            }),
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue
            }
        });
```

But my requirement is to follow the document by dynamic user not current user.
Is it possible to achieve that functionality no matter we user Rest Api, CSOM, SSOM or PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: No.

Longer Answer:

And No it won't work and there is no Rest API/PowerShell/etc. solution for **follow**.

From the API documentation for [follow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/following-people-and-content-rest-api-reference-for-sharepoint#follow):

> Follow
>   Makes the current user start following a user, document, site, or tag.

There is only one method to follow items, and it explicitly uses the currently logged in user credentials to validate the user in order to follow the item. There are no other parameters or functions to enroll a generic user to follow.

This makes sense. Remember, SharePoint is also used for public sites as well. One of the original intentions of follow was for blogs. They have to only allow opt-in requests for following because adding people without consent would violate most privacy policies, and GDPR, etc. This is why they don't allow it.

Since you can't explicitly enroll people to follow, if the need is to set up notifications (**not follow**), then your only other real option is to set up a workflow with triggers etc.